# UISearchBar- change scope without greying out table?

Tags: iphone, scope, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, first-responder

How can I allow a change in scope without having the table grey out, the search field become first responder and keyboard popup?

I simply want to refresh the data shown based on the scope.

Comment: What is triggering the change in scope?  (user input, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this with following:

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {
    BOOL shouldBeginEditing;
}

@end  

@implementation SearchViewController

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)bar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    shouldBeginEditing = NO;
}

-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)bar
{   
    if (shouldBeginEditing)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        shouldBeginEditing = YES;
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the scope using the standard UISearchBar scope buttons override the [searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchScope](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchDisplayDelegate/searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:) method in your UISearchDisplayDelegate and have it do whatever you need it to.